# notation for a torus

Tags: geometry, notation, differential-topology

I am trying to search for the meaning of this notation but unfortunately it seems that wikipedia even doesn't have it. The book I am following uses the following notation for a torus: $\mathbb{T}^d = \mathbb{R}^d/\mathbb{Z}^d$. What does this mean? I 've never seen this notation before.

Comment: It's defining the $d$-dimensional torus as the [quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) of the group $\mathbb{R}^d$ by the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the torus is the quotient of the Lie group $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the discrete subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^n$. It has natural structure of a smooth manifold. This comes from a general theorem that any quotient $G/H$ of a Lie group by a closed Lie subgroup is a manifold.

If you don't need the smooth manifold structure, then you can consider this quotient just as a quotient of abstract (abelian) groups.

Comment: that should be "any quotient of a Lie group by a _closed_ Lie subgroup is a manifold."  The quotient of the 2-torus by a dense 1-dimensional subgroup has the trivial topology, and hence is not a manifold.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you! I have edited this.